# How to change the date string to date time with local timezone in js?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I use date picker and i get the value of the date picker as

> document.getElementById("id_of_datepicker")

and when i change this to date using

> new Date(document.getElementById("id_of_datepicker"));

it returns

> Thu Feb 06 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

and what i look for is instead of passing the dates as i do i need to send it in local timezone with 00 hours, min, secs which then has to be converted to utc. how can i do this?
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to split it manually and use `Date.UTC` for utc function like this:

```
var dateStr = document.getElementById("id_of_datepicker");
var dateArr = dateStr.split(/[\-T:]/);//suppose it is like 2014-06-12T00:00:00
var localTime=new Date(Date.parse(dateArr[0],dateArr[1],dateArr[2]), 0, 0, 0)
var utcTime=new Date(Date.UTC(dateArr[0],dateArr[1],dateArr[2]), 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date/time manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this the dt value returned by the date object
 Thu Feb 06 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

```
 Date dt=new Date();
 dat=dt.getFullYear()+'-'+dt.getMonth()+'-'+dt.getDate();
```

It will return date dt print in yyyy-mm-dd format ot you can change in your desired format

Comment: pass the date returning object in date method and use this, hope your problem will resolve